# Is the pronoun 'themselves' offset by commas like an appositive?

Tags: commas, pronouns, appositives

For example: would this sentence be correct?

Termites, themselves, can't break down the cellulose either.

Comment: What have you found the common practice to be in articles on the internet? What does [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/themselves) indicate?

Answer (score 1):

No commas. 'Themselves' is not extra info, just emphasis.